# python map string split list

Tags: python, string, parsing, functional-programming

I am trying to map the `str.split` function to an array of string. namely, I would like to split all the strings in a string array that follow the same format. Any idea how to do that with `map` in python? For example let's assume we have a list like this:

```
a = ['2011-12-22 46:31:11','2011-12-20 20:19:17', '2011-12-20 01:09:21']
```

want to split the strings by space ( `split(" ")`) using map to have a list as:

```
[['2011-12-22', '46:31:11'], ['2011-12-20', '20:19:17'], ['2011-12-20', '01:09:21']]
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Though it isn't well known, there is a function designed just for this purpose, [operator.methodcaller](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.methodcaller):

```
>>> from operator import methodcaller
>>> a = ['2011-12-22 46:31:11','2011-12-20 20:19:17', '2011-12-20 01:09:21']
>>> list(map(methodcaller("split", " "), a))
[['2011-12-22', '46:31:11'], ['2011-12-20', '20:19:17'], ['2011-12-20', '01:09:21']]
```

This technique is faster than equivalent approaches using lambda expressions.

Comment: This is the absolutely best answer, because it allows me to pass the `str.split` keyword argument `sep=" "` to the `str.split` function. I'm not sure how that could be accomplished otherwise, because `map(str.split('\t'), a)` does not work. Thanks!

Answer (score 42):

```
map(lambda x: x.split(), a)
```

but, using a list comprehension

```
[x.split() for x in a]
```

is much clearer in this case.

Comment: Even though the OP asks explicitly for `map`, this answer shows that it's cleaner and more Pythonic to use a list comprehension.

Comment: @kojiro That is very subjective.  Coming from a Functional Programming background, the map is much easier to read/cleaner than a list comprehension (to me).

Answer (score 10):

This is how I do it:

```
>>> a=['2011-12-22 46:31:11','2011-12-20 20:19:17', '2011-12-20 01:09:21']
>>> map(str.split, a)
[['2011-12-22', '46:31:11'], ['2011-12-20', '20:19:17'], ['2011-12-20', '01:09:21']]
```

This only works when you know you have a list of `str` (i.e. not just a list of things that implement the `split` method in a way compatible with `str`). It also relies on using the default behaviour of `split()`, which splits on any whitespace, rather than using `x.split(' ')`, which splits on space characters only (i.e. not tabs, newlines, or other whitespace), because you can't pass another argument using this method. For calling behaviour more complex than this, I would use a list comprehension.

Comment: How to give arguments to split like "\t" and "1" like that

Comment: @Vignesh "For calling behaviour more complex than this, I would use a list comprehension". The thing you're mapping over the list has to be callable with one argument. You can always wrap the split method call in a new function (possibly defined inline using lambda), in order to make something that can be called with one argument and which will also pass the additional separator argument. But that usually ends up less readable than `[x.split('\t') for x in a]`, unless it's something you would have defined and named anyway.

Answer (score 9):

Use [`map`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) in conjunction with a function. A neat way is to use a [lambda](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-forms) function:

```
>>> a=['2011-12-22 46:31:11','2011-12-20 20:19:17', '2011-12-20 01:09:21']
>>> map(lambda s: s.split(), a)
[['2011-12-22', '46:31:11'], ['2011-12-20', '20:19:17'],
 ['2011-12-20', '01:09:21']]
```

Comment: you could simplify with `map(str.split, a)`

Answer (score 2):

**Community wiki answer to compare other answers given**

```
>>> from timeit import Timer
>>> t = {}
>>> t['methodcaller'] = Timer("map(methodcaller('split', ' '), a)", "from operator import methodcaller; a=['2011-12-22 46:31:11','2011-12-20 20:19:17', '2011-12-20 01:09:21']")
>>> t['lambda'] = Timer("map(lambda s: s.split(), a)", "a = ['2011-12-22 46:31:11','2011-12-20 20:19:17', '2011-12-20 01:09:21']")
>>> t['listcomp'] = Timer("[s.split() for s in a]", "a = ['2011-12-22 46:31:11','2011-12-20 20:19:17', '2011-12-20 01:09:21']")
>>> for name, timer in t.items():
...     print '%s: %.2f usec/pass' % (name, 1000000 * timer.timeit(number=100000)/100000)
... 
listcomp: 2.08 usec/pass
methodcaller: 2.87 usec/pass
lambda: 3.10 usec/pass
```

Comment: Amusing how they ended up in order according to speed.