# Python: Split a list where blank space

Tags: python, python-3.x

I believe I have a beginner's question which I haven't been able to find a solution for. Perhaps somebody here knows how to solve it?

I have a list of 250 rows. Each row contains 8 elements, currently separated by one blank space (see the first and last five lines copied below). As I understand it, python currently treats each row as a string. So my list contains 250 strings.

I would like to convert the current list of 250 strings (each one including 8 elements separated by blank space) into a matrix of 250 rows and 8 columns. Is there a way to do this efficiently?

```
Out[2]: 
['-20.8 -83.6 19:32 13:57 2014 01 22 165.8',
 '-17.2 -84.5 19:33 13:55 2014 01 22 269.9',
 '-13.6 -85.3 19:34 13:53 2014 01 22 674.3',
 '-16.8 -109.3 21:12 13:55 2014 01 22 734.9',
 '-13.2 -110.1 21:13 13:53 2014 01 22 699.3',
...
 '14.0 -145.4 23:18 13:37 2014 12 29 295.8',
 '10.4 -144.6 23:17 13:39 2014 12 29 685.7',
 '17.6 -146.2 23:19 13:34 2014 12 29 202.4',
 '18.0 -171.0 00:58 13:34 2014 12 30 308.0',
 '21.6 -171.8 00:59 13:32 2014 12 30 533.7']
```

Comment: Try `[r.split() for r in output]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python map string split list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8461230/python-map-string-split-list)

Comment: @user3080953 Note the last answer in that question https://stackoverflow.com/a/8461414/4819449. List comprehension is fastest and clearest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a list-comp with `str.split`:

```
>>> l = ['1 2 3',
...      '4 5 6',
...      '7 8 9']
>>> [r.split() for r in l]
[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9']]
```

Comment: @ Joe Iddon Thank you! Very elegant!

Comment: @kirerik: Please accept the answer if it solved your problem (you can click the small check next to the answer which then turns green).

Answer (score 2):

```
some_list = ['-20.8 -83.6 19:32 13:57 2014 01 22 165.8', '-17.2 -84.5 19:33 13:55 2014 01 22 269.9', '-13.6 -85.3 19:34 13:53 2014 01 22 674.3', '-16.8 -109.3 21:12 13:55 2014 01 22 734.9', '-13.2 -110.1 21:13 13:53 2014 01 22 699.3']

new_list = [item.split() for item in some_list]
print(new_list)
```